# How to add an Administration/Monitoring interface to an ASP.net Core WebDAV Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am developing a WebDAV connection for a database based ECM system using the IT HIT WebDAV engine and ASP.net Core 5.

I would like to add a kind of "monitoring interface" to this WebDAV server.
So that when the administrator enters a certain URL into a web browser, a status page is displayed listing internal state data of the WebDAV server (e.g. number of active sessions, list of locked files or something like that).

How could I implement this?

The WebDAV server has no routing, but the URLs are mapped directly to the resources.
I.e. it wouldn't work to set a specific URL for the status page, because it would be interpreted as a WebDAV resource.
I could use something like a well-known URI, e.g.
`https://mywebdavserver.com:8443/.well-known/monitoring`
and then define a different processing path for this URL via middleware.
But this would mean that there should not be a subdirectory named .well-known in the WebDAV root directory, because it (and the resources it contains) would not be found.
I would want to avoid such a restriction if possible.

I was thinking about using a second port for administrative purposes, but how do I do that in an ASP.net Core 5 project? I know that you can define different processing paths for different URLs via middleware, but I haven't found a way to make this distinction based on the port number in that context.

Alternatively, I could set up a second service for the administration tasks. But then the question arises: How do I get to the internal data of the WebDAV service with that? Again, the WebDAV service would need an interface through which the administration service could query the data.

Personally, I would prefer the variant with the second port to the variant with the well-known URI, because that would mean a cleaner separation of data and administration.
But how do I do that?